# Java - Looping Concept

Tags: java, for-loop, string-concatenation

Write a method named repl that accepts a String and a number of repetitions as parameters and returns the String concatenated that many times. For example, the call `repl("hello", 3)` returns "hellohellohello". If the number of repetitions is 0 or less, an empty string is returned.

I have tried:

```
public String repl(String x,int y){
    if(y<=0){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return x;
    }

}
```

Somehow I cannot print hello 3 times. My output is only once .Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have put in **ZERO** effort.

Comment: So you mean i am in the wrong direction?Then i shall think of something else.

Comment: Since this looks like a homework question, I'll ask you instead.  You are returning the input string unmodified, so you'll get back just one copy.  What would you have to do to make it return three copies strung together? Hint: java.util.StringBuilder

Comment: @jahroy From our perspective it looks like zero effort, but I'm inclined to give the benefit of the doubt on this one.

Comment: -I did by creating the method as told.The question states "If the number of repetitions is 0 or less, an empty string is returned." I tried doing all these.And where did i not try?

Comment: I think this question genuinely demonstrates **ZERO** effot.  The OP has simply provided the most basic skeleton code imagineable.  He returns null or returns the input.  How can he claim that that is an attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Isnt an empty string null?

Comment: So if i am at the wrong direction,just tell me.Dont tell me i am not showing effort.I am new to java so i may be rather weak.But i am definitely trying.Just to clarify.

Comment: No.  An empty String and null are two different things.  The best thing you could do to help solve this problem is pay attention in class or go do some Java tutorials.  It's not our job to teach you Java from scratch.

Comment: Definitely a rude person.By the way,this is not a homework.I know i am weak so i am doing some free exercises on java on the internet.This question is taken from practiceit.Seriously,you are rude.

Comment: If i am lazy,i wont even try attempting those free exercises online to brush up on my skills.

Comment: It looks like you started trying to solve the issue using recursion, but then forgot the recursion step...

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx - I'm mystified that this could be mistaken for an attempt at recursion... or an attempt of any kind!

Comment: @jahroy The `if (y<=0)` construct looks like a distinction between a trivial and non-trivial case.  It's not that far fetched; just replace the `return null` with `return ""` and `return x` with `return x+repl(x, y-1)` and you're there.  It's closer to a recursive solution than to a looping one, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm retracting my `-1` vote and will try to explain (NOT solve the question), although it definitely has nothing to do with how good you are at java. These are simple general programming concepts... And you *should* start from the absolute beginnings if you want to *really* teach yourself programming.

Anyway, so here you are :

#### Try analyzing WHAT you want your code to do

And I mean, "as if" you're telling **me** how to do it. Think about the way **you** would do the requested job, that's the only way you can learn to program.

---

So, you said you want to type `X` as many times as you wish (e.g. `Y`).

The programming-way to do it would be (let's make it in the form of a conversation between 2 people) :

- **Person A :** Type 3 times "Hello"
- **Person B :** OK. Let me think about it.
- **Person B :** 1 "hello"s (Have I reached 3 times yet? Nope. So, let's continue)
- **Person B :** 2 "hello"s (Have I reached 3 times yet? Nope. So, let's continue)
- **Person B :** 3 "hello"s (Have I reached 3 times yet? Yep. OK, so that was it)

I'm not sure if I have helped, but I definitely hope so.

---

**Hint :** Have a look at the `for` statement and **loops**.

**Sidenote :** Your `if y<=0` logic *is* correct, though it is quite redundant.

Answer (score -2):

```
public String repl(String x,int y){
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++) sb.append(x);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I am repeating same comment, just providing ready-made code doesn't help OP to learn by himself.